# Android - Is this Code correct?

Tags: android

is the below mentioned code correct

```
public boolean checkRecipe(CharSequence recipename) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor checkRecursor=rDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_TITLE}, 
                KEY_TITLE+"="+recipename, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(checkRecursor!=null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

I'm trying to check whether a given entry is present in the table or not.

Comment: What does rDb.query do? You should create one database cursor for your class and use it throughout, creating a new cursor for each call is a bad idea.

Comment: I have done all that.
Was trying to check whehter a given entry is there in the table under the "title" field.
I got this error when i wanted to search for abc
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: abc: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT title FROM recipes WHERE title=abc

Comment: return (checkRecursor != null);

Comment: Basically I have used a AutoCompleteTextView to enter the data. When I click on "Get data" the above action should be done.

Comment: Can you please post the code for rDb.query() then, as it is impossible to help you without it. The call rDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_TITLE}, KEY_TITLE+"="+recipename, null, null, null, null, null); is meaningless on its own.

Comment: @fredley

I'm using this function

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recipename is a string, you must put quotes around it

```
Cursor checkRecursor=rDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_TITLE}, 
            KEY_TITLE+"= '"+recipename + "'", null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I did this KEY_TITLE+"="+"\""+recipename+"\""

Thank you fedj